# In Django. How could I update a field with a button in the same HTML page?

Tags: python-3.x, django-views

New in Django. I have a page that registered a previous date in a field ( I simulated 8 days back).  In the same page I have a button that will perform a function that update the same field to "Today".   It looks that after push the button it will ignore the function  "xxx".   I will incorporate some database calls after resolve this issue, so probably it will be convenient to use "POST" method.  Please assist.

After push the button, it should perform the xxx function, but this one is ignored and the date-field does not change.

```
# &&& HTML &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

<form action= '' method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<P> {{actualdate}} </P>
<input type="submit" value="UPADATE !"> 
</form>

# &&& VIEWS &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& 
def home(request):
    actualdatex = date.today() - timedelta(days=8) 
    context1={'actualdate': actualdatex}             
    return render(request, "home.html", context1 )

def xxx(request):   
    actualdatex  =  request.POST.get('actualdate')
    actualdatex = date.today() 
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'actualdate': actualdatex})

#&&& URLS &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

from django.urls import path
from . import views
    urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('', views.xxx, name='xxx' ),
]
```

The page remains unchanged after the first load.